# Import Error Django-profiles

Tags: django

I'm trying to get the django-profiles work.

I follow the steps of [this manual ("The Missing Manual")](http://birdhouse.org/blog/2009/06/27/django-profiles/),

so:

- I work in the same project I also use for the django-registration (so no app created!!!)
- In my templates I've created a folder "/profiles" (including edit_profile.html)
- My AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE is set to 'myProjectName.UserProfile'
- I've created in my project folder models.py containing:

  ```
  from django.db import models

  class UserProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
      first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=100)
      middle_name = models.CharField(_('middle name'), blank=True, max_length=100)
      last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=100)
      birth_date = models.DateField(_('birth date'), blank=True, null=True)
  ```
- In my project folder, I've created forms.py, with exactly the same code as in the manual
- In urls.py  of my project I've added:

  ```
  from myProjectName.forms import ProfileForm
      ('^profiles/edit', 'profiles.views.edit_profile',{'form_class':ProfileForm,'success_url':'/my/custom/url',}),
      (r'^profiles/', include('profiles.urls')),
  ```

  So now the whole urls.py file of my project is:

  ```
  from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
  from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
  from django.contrib import admin
  from myProjectName.forms import ProfileForm
  admin.autodiscover()

  urlpatterns = patterns('',
      (r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      (r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
      (r'^$', direct_to_template,
      { 'template': 'index.html' }, 'index'),
      ('^profiles/edit', 'profiles.views.edit_profile', {'form_class': ProfileForm,'success_url':'/my/custom/url',}),
      (r'^profiles/', include('profiles.urls')),
  )
  ```

  When I access now http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/edit/, I get this error:

  ```
  Exception Value:    No module named ourcrestmont.itaco.models
  ```

  That's the import located in forms.py ...

  What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

The code of my forms.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from ourcrestmont.itaco.models import *

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Foo
      exclude = ('field1','field2','field3',)
```

It's exactly the same code as in the manual, or is this code not good? (could anyone give an other, better code?)

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but did you definitely install the module & also include it in your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

Comment: Yes, 'registration' and 'profiles' are successfully installed and both included in the INSTALLED_APPS. But do I have to create an app, or could I get it also work only with a project-folder?

Comment: Can you show us your custom profileform code also, including the imports at the top of it?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that import there, you aren't referencing anything from itaco.models (that I can see)

Comment: Can anybody give me a working example code to make forms.py work? And do I also need a signals.py program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that import statement appears to be attempting to import a file called "ourcrestmont/itaco/models.py". Make sure that exists.

(by django model, that looks like it is a project called ourcrestmont with an app called itaco)

If it exists, make sure that itaco and ourcrestmont both have **init**.py files in them.

You *can* just have the project (the import line in that case is from projectname.models import modelname) but I'd recommend sticking to the standard layout and putting your models, forms and views together in an App beneath a project, even if you only currently see your project as having one App. (Because it doesn't, it has at least three, since registration and profiles are *also* django apps, they're just django apps outside of what you've made, if you see what I mean, and thinking of it like that might make dependancy and inclusion bugs easier to solve. Certainly every other django app is going to assume most things are inside an app)

Comment: I dont now what kind of file the "ourcrestmont/itaco/models.py" is, it's the import the manual also use, with no further information about it... So it would be strange I don't have it. Google don't find any information about this file...?!